# OrientDB: How to use MATCH in an UPDATE operation?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Is it possible to use MATCH in an UPDATE operation? I've tried things like this:

```
UPDATE (MATCH...RETURN...) SET...
```

I assumed it would work, since this does:

```
UPDATE #12:34 SET...
```

But I've not been successful with any syntax I could come up with.

So if this is supported, what is the correct syntax to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but the MATCH has to return persistent records, eg.

`RETURN $elements`

or (in v 3.0)

`RETURN expand(x)`

If you are using v 3.0, please consider that you just gave me a chance to find a bug (thank you!), so you will have a NullPointerException on the RC2. I already fixed it, the fix will be in the snapshot in a few minutes and will be released with the first 3.0.0 GA

Comment: Thanks Luigi. I'll try that later today. Any thoughts on [my other MATCH question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460138/orientdb-efficient-way-to-select-records-with-a-value-equal-to-the-max-of-all-s)?

Comment: Well, it works (using RETURN $elements), but since my MATCH statement includes both V and E subclasses, the UPDATE is applied to both of them. Is there a way to return $elements for only a specific class (in v2.2)? I assume that in v3.0, the expand(x) syntax supports x as being a class name declared with "as:"?

Comment: In v 2.2 you can use a `SELECT expand(x) FROM (MATCH ... RETURN x)`

Answer (score 1):

it works well

```
UPDATE EDGE Custom_Family_Of_Custom 
SET survey_status = 'value_1'
WHERE @rid in (
SELECT level1_e.@rid FROM (
MATCH {class: Custom, as: custom, where: (custom_uuid = 'param_uuid_1')}
.bothE('Custom_Family_Of_Custom') {as: e} 
.bothV('Custom') {as: v, where: (custom_uuid = 'param_uuid_2')} 
return e
)
)
```