# OrientDB: Efficient way to select records with a value equal to the max of all such values?

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I'm not sure how to do this without using a JOIN (which ODB doesn't have, of course). In "generic" SQL, you might do something like this:

```
Select * FROM table
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT max(field) AS max_of_field, key FROM table GROUP BY key) sub
ON table.field = sub.max_of_field AND table.key = sub.key
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in ODB, using SELECT and/or MATCH?

Comment: PS - The objective here is to select the "last" or "most recent" ('field' in the example is a numeric timestamp) of many records (each identified by 'key'). I've found several ways to do this for _one record_ (using a let), and of course it's simple to select all of the records, but I've not found an efficient way to find the "last" of many records.

Comment: Did you try just running an order by ont hat field and select the highest one from that first quesry in a next one?

Comment: @mitchken - Thanks for the idea. I'll try it out.

Comment: @mitchken - Well, if there's a way to do it the way you suggest, I can't figure out it. I can see how your suggestion would easily produce the desired result if I only cared about one 'key', but the trick here is that I'm not just looking for one record, I'm looking for the "last" (max of the 'field' column) of many different records, based on the 'key' column.

Comment: Could you send what you have currently, since my mySQL is rather outdated compared to OrientSQL.
Add it to the issue and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: This is what I ended up with: `SELECT key, max(x) AS x FROM table GROUP BY key`. There are lots of "old" comments and other SO questions that show problems with the ODB GROUP BY logic, but based on my testing, it does seem to produce the right results. However, GROUP BY only supports a single field. That's fine for this use-case, but it's still not a "universal solution" (like the INNER JOIN, which has no such limit).